# Special Characters on Console

Tags: c++, console, ascii, special-characters

I've finished my poker game but now I want to make it look a bit better with displaying Spades, Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs. I tried this answer: [C++: Printing ASCII Heart and Diamonds With Platform Independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094366/c-printing-ascii-heart-and-diamonds-with-platform-independent)

Maybe stupid but I try:

```
cout << 'U+2662' << endl;
```

I don't know how to write it.

Comment: How could you not make it work? Where could you not make it work? As it is, your question is the duplicate of the linked one, since you add no more information to it.

Comment: Please post the relevant section(s) of code that isn't/aren't working.

Comment: If you guys were real hackers, you'd be able to instantly diagnose "it doesn't work."

Comment: Can your Windows console handle UTF-8 output?

Comment: It should be "I don't know how to write it", sorry. cout << "U+2662" << endl ?

Comment: @WhirlWind:  You should see what I bill as a combination hacker and telepath.  I have to, really, considering the Psi Corps cut.

Comment: You guys are so funny, I'm looking for vomit smileys..

Comment: @pocoa modify your question to include your comment about `cout`.

Comment: @pocoa, vomit smileys wouldn't help, you've already admitted you don't know how to make the characters come out right.

Comment: @meager I've modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a UTF-8 character, you need to encode it as hex bytes. I'll steal [this link to fileinfo.com](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2665/index.htm) from an answer to the question you linked - if you jump to the UTF-8 representation, it says `0xE2 0x99 0xA5` and you can convert that to `"\xE2\x99\xA5"` as a string.

However I can't guarantee that your console will display UTF-8 so this answer might not help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. With the above string, it displays: â™¥? I guess if I can find the right ones, it'll display correctly.

Comment: I think you've just proven what I already suspected, the console doesn't use UTF-8. Did you try the code that was presented in your linked question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to use the old ASCII control characters in the Windows console, you can use:

```
cout << (char) 3 << (char) 4 << (char) 5 << (char) 6 << endl;
//hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades
```

This isn't Unicode, and I assume it is not very portable.  I don't really know of a portable solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `std::wcout` and use UTF-16 by encoding as hex bytes (as Mark answers), but I can't guarantee that any of your characters will display correctly on Windows (before Vista?) because the Windows console was never really intended for this sort of thing. You can use `wcout` with Visual Studio and maybe Cygwin, but I don't think MinGW supports it. Make sure to use wide character literals: `L"string"`.

Alternatively, you can use the preprocessor to supply the correct definitions of constants for each platform. I imagine that there will be at most three—ASCII on older platforms, UTF-8 on the more modern, and UTF-16 (with `wcout`) on newer Windows.

Comment: There should be an easy way, like Mark's example.

Comment: My compiler does not run this code "wcout << "\xE2\x99\xA5" << endl", says "warning: unused variable 'wcout'". I'm using Eclipse with MinGW 5.1.6.